# Why I get BadMethodCallException?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my seeder class, I am calling a method that is defined in a User model:

Like this:

```
$user = User::where('email', 'user1@teams.com')->get();
$user->test();
```

My User model:

```
    class User extends Authenticatable
    {

        public function test()
        {
            return "!!";
        }
    }
```

But, when run the seed, I get this error:

```
  [BadMethodCallException]
  Method test does not exist.
```

Comment: first create a new instance of User class.Then access that test method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the $user contains a collection of users since you are using get(). You can use first() instead.
So the new code should be:

```
$user = User::where('email', 'user1@teams.com')->first();
```